# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar el Qtablewidget o mostrar los nuevos registros junto a los ya impresos en el Qtablewidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Estoy trabajando con QtableWidget, creado en QtDesigner. A través de él muestro información de una base de datos presionando un botón, cuando el Qtablewidget está vacío imprime correctamente los registros que se encuentran en la base de datos, pero tengo un problema. Cuando ingreso nueva información a la base de datos y quiero refrescar el Qtablewidget (previamente llenado) para mostrar estos nuevos registros, no pasa, no muestra los nuevos registros. ¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Aquí hay una imagen del Qtablewidget completo. El botón ("actualizar") llama a la función para llenar la Qtable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
import sys
from front_menu import *  #Diseño en Qt Designer
import conexion           #Conexion a base de datos


class MiApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow() 
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.datos = conexion.Registro_datos()
        self.ui.btn_refrescar.clicked.connect(self.mostrar_trazas)
        
    def mostrar_trazas(self):
        datos = self.datos.buscar_trazas()
        i = len(datos)
        self.ui.tabla_trazas.setRowCount(i)
        tablerow = 0

        for row in datos:
            self.Id = row [0]
            self.ui.tabla_trazas.setItem(tablerow,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1])))
            self.ui.tabla_trazas.setItem(tablerow,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[2]))
            self.ui.tabla_trazas.setItem(tablerow,2,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[3]))
            self.ui.tabla_trazas.setItem(tablerow,3,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[4]))
            self.ui.tabla_trazas.setItem(tablerow,4,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[5]))
            tablerow +=1
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mi_app = MiApp()
    mi_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Intenta llamar al método `update()`. Algo como  `self.ui.tabla_trazas.viewport().update()` al final de la función `mostrar_trazas(self)`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, aunque hoy no logro mostrar los nuevos registros

Comment: Hice un código de prueba y se me está actualizando perfectamente, quizá los datos realmente no cambiaron, entonces muestra lo mismo que antes.